# Access nested stack views

Tags: swift, swift3, uistackview

Obviously overseeing something simple. Need to access a *nested* stack view in *another* stack view.

**If I wanted to set spacing to all nested stackViews for passenger 2 how would I do that?**

```
// Select passenger 2
let tag = 2

// Select wrapper stackView for passenger 2
let stackView = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as! UIStackView!

let nestedStackViews = stackView. <-- WHAT GOES HERE??

for sv in nestedStackViews{
    sv?.spacing = 0 // Set nested stackView spacing to 0 to avoid constraint issues
}
```

**To Visualize (need to set spacing of firstName_P2, surname_P2 and email_P2 to 0)**
[image]

**SOLUTION: Based on Winter's answer**

Providing more detail for others who might be struggling, make sure to convert the subview to a stackview

```
// Select passenger 2
let tag = 2

// Select wrapper stackView for passenger 2
let stackView = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as! UIStackView!

if let nestedStackViews = stackView?.subviews{
    for sv in nestedStackViews{
        let nsv = sv as! UIStackView
        nsv.spacing = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [subviews](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622614-subviews): `stackView.subviews`

Comment: Thanks!  Had tried it before - but seeing it from you made me realize to convert the subview to a stack view.