# Swift - UIPanRecognizer in a UIStackView

Tags: user-interface, layout, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uistackview

I want to make a UIPanRecognizer in a UIStackView. [The UI looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtB0P.png)

There's a big square which is a StackView which contains 9 labels.
My goal is when I start to drag my finger within the StackView and if a label contains that touchpoint then its color should be blue and on and on. If I lift my finger all of the labels background color turn back to white.
The labels are in a OutletCollection.
Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet var testLabels: [UILabel]!
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var touchedPoint: CGPoint!
    if let view = recognizer.view{
        if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {
            touchedPoint = recognizer.location(in: view)
            for index in testLabels.indices {

                if testLabels[index].frame.contains(touchedPoint) {

                    testLabels[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

                }
            }
        }
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            for index in testLabels.indices {

                testLabels[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            }
        }
    }
```

Right now when I touch for example the top-left square and start to drag my finger to the right the whole first column turns blue then the second then the third. That happens when I touch any labels of the first row, but nothing happens when I touch the other squares.
First time, I tried to solve my problem by handle the squares just as an OutletCollection (without the StackView) and the recognizer just worked fine! The reason why I experiment with the StackView that it's so easier to make the layout(just a few constraints needed, without the StackView it is a nightmare).
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.
**Edit: probably this one helps?**

> [Access nested stack views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429256/access-nested-stack-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each label is a subview of its containing stack view (which is also probably a subview of a stack view), and each label has its own coordinate space.

Assuming your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is assigned to the view controller's view, you need to translate the coordinates / frames.

This should work for you:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var touchedPoint: CGPoint!

    if let view = recognizer.view{

        if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {

            touchedPoint = recognizer.location(in: view)

            for index in testLabels.indices {

                // translate / convert the label's bounds from its frame to the view's coordinate space
                let testFrame = view.convert(testLabels[index].bounds, from:testLabels[index] )

                // check the resulting testFrame for the point                  
                if testFrame.contains(touchedPoint) {

                    testLabels[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

                }
            }
        }
        else if recognizer.state == .ended {
            for index in testLabels.indices {

                testLabels[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also simplify your code a bit by using `for object in collection` instead of indices. This is functionally the same as above, but maybe a little simpler:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var touchedPoint: CGPoint!

    if let view = recognizer.view{

        if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {

            touchedPoint = recognizer.location(in: view)

            for lbl in testLabels {

                // translate / convert the label's bounds from its frame to the view's coordinate space
                let testFrame = view.convert(lbl.bounds, from:lbl )

                // check the resulting testFrame for the point
                if testFrame.contains(touchedPoint) {

                    lbl.backgroundColor = .blue

                }
            }
        }
        else if recognizer.state == .ended {
            for lbl in testLabels {

                lbl.backgroundColor = .white

            }
        }
    }
}
```