# How do I use TouchDragEnter on UICollectionView's Cells?

Tags: ios, swift

this is my first question so any suggestions on how to write better Questions on stackoverflow will also be appreciated!

Ok, so I have a UICollectionView with a bunch of cells, and let's say that on a device, the user touches the first cell and then glides over the other cells without lifting her finger. I'm trying to figure out how to call a function (that is specific to every cell) whenever **the user's finger slides out of the current cell and into the area of another**. From what I understand, I think it's like the TouchDragEnter event for UIButtons (maybe).

Right now, if a user drags her finger over the cells it simply fires the function associated to the first cell she touched, but none of the others. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please refer to UIResponder documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan

Comment: @inokey - Ok, then please be so awesome and tell me **how** to read this documentation to **understand what code to write where** in order to apply this? I'm not seeing anything about UICollectionViews and its cells here... thanks in adv!

Comment: Basically `UICollectionView` is a `UIView`, so it should trigger event touchesBegan. The `UITouch` set that is passed in this method will contain set of UITouches that are occurring. And the `UITouch` itself has a reference to the view that is associated with this touch `UITouch.view`

Answer (score 0):

Controls, such as `UIButton`, respond to touch drag events only if the event *starts* in that control. From Apple's docs for `touchDragEnter`:

> This event is delivered only if the touch originated inside the control's bounds, exited the bounds, and then entered the bounds again.

If you want to detect dragging from *outside* to *inside* of an object, you probably want to use `touchesBegan` / `touchesMoved` / `touchesEnded` or `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in the superview.

Here's a bit of example code that you may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52010135/6257435

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I'll spend some time on this, and once it's all done I'll post the code up here and mark ur response as answer! fingers crossed~